# Saving an activity's/fragment's state

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

Let's assume I have an activity inside of which I have one fragment (and only one fragment).

I want to preserve the fragment's state in case of rotation. I have two options:

Option A) Preserving the Activity's state.

Option B) Preserving the Fragment's state.

What's exactly the difference? Preserving the Activity state will do the job, as will preserving the Fragment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should save the state in where it belongs to. This will allow for easier modifying your app in the future because it reduces the dependencies between components.

Suppose, you have in your `ListFragment` `currentPosition`. You can save it in the enclosing activity but then your `Ativity` will know about the internal state of your `Fragment` which might be not necessary. One day you do not need   currentPosition anymore and, if saved only within a Fragment, your other components can be left intact. Same for adding something to the state.

In general I would define a `static` inner `State` class, probably `extending Parcelable`, for every stateful component and save any inner fields you need in there. The `State` class has to be `static` though

Answer (score 0):

It's up to you.
If you don't have anything specific in your activity you can do it in your fragment.

The other option is to to add `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file for your activity, then any rotation change will trigger `android.app.Activity#onConfigurationChanged` in your Activity when you can do what you need to do on rotation.

In this later case, your activity and fragment will not be re-created by the framework and so the layout will not be changed (onCreate will not be called). So becareful.

Comment: Useful answer as well!